# Thin large subspaces of $\ell^N_1$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider a sequence $V_N$ of subspaces of $\ell^N_1$ so that $\dim V_N = N- n$ and $n$ is $\mathsf{o}(N)$. Is it true that these spaces are "thick" (unofficial terminology), i.e. are there constants $K_1,K_2>0$ so that for $N$ large enough,
$$
\sup_{x \in V, \|x\|_1 \leq K_1} \|x\|_\infty \geq K_2
$$
where $\|x\|_\infty$ is (as usual) the supremum of the coordinates of $x$.

A relaxation (or equivalent formulation?) of the above: is there a sequence $x_i \in V_i \subset \ell_1^i \subset \ell_1\mathbb{N}$ which is convergent in the weak$^*$ topology of $\ell_1 \mathbb{N}$ to something else than $0$?

In the $\ell_2$ case, the answer is "overwhelmingly positive". Let $\lbrace e_i\rbrace_{i=1}^N$ be the "standard" basis of $\ell^N_1$. Consider $P_{V_N}$ to be the orthogonal projection on $V_N$, then 
$$
N-n = \dim V_N = \sum_{i=1}^N \langle P_{V_N} e_i \mid e_i \rangle
$$
So that, in fact, there are at least $N-2n$ coordinates $i$ so that  $\langle P_V e_i \mid e_i \rangle \geq \frac{1}{2}$ and $\langle P_{V_N} e_i \mid e_i \rangle = \| P_{V_N} e_i\|_2^2 \leq 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Improved version of my answer.  The following version of Kashin's
(1977) result is needed here: For any $\alpha\in(0,1)$ there
exists $C=C(\alpha)$ such that for any $N$ there is an
$\lceil\alpha N\rceil$-dimensional subspace $L$ of $\ell^N_1$
satisfying
$$\forall x\in L\quad
\frac1{\sqrt{N}}||x||_1\le||x||_2\le\frac{C}{\sqrt{N}}||x||_1$$
(see e.g. Section 1.10.3 in Brazitikos, Giannopoulos, Valettas,
Vritsiou, Geometry of isotropic convex bodies. American
Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2014).

This can be used to show that there is a sequence
$(N(i))$ tending to $\infty$ and subspaces $V_{N(i)}$ of  $\ell_1^{N(i)}$ so that dim$V_{N(i)}/N(i)\ge(1-\frac1i)$ and

$$
\sup_{x \in V_{N(i)}, \|x\|_1 \leq 1} \|x\|_2 \le\frac1i.
$$

Since $\|x\|_\infty\le ||x||_2$ this implies that the answer to the first question is `No'.

We apply Kashin's theorem with $\alpha=1-\frac1i$, let $C$ be the
corresponding constant. We pick $N(i)$ so large that $N(i)>i$ and
$$\frac{C}{\sqrt{N(i)}}\le\frac 1i.$$
Let $V_{N(i)}$ be the subspace $L$ of the Kashin's theorem
corresponding to this situation. It is easy to check that all of
the conditions above are satisfied.

Comment: interesting, thanks! So you could get a counterexample if (say) $n = N^{2/3}$ but perhaps not if (say) $n= N^{1/2}$? (the choice of exponent is random and arbitrary! it was just meant to illustrate) More precisely: if there are functions $f(N)$ which are $o(N)$ so that counterexamples can be produced, what are the best function?

Comment: I did not think in such terms. I meant: suppose you want to show that for sufficiently large N you can pick $n=0.0001N$ such that the supremum is $<0.001$. You look at the distance-to-Euclidean constant $C$ in Kashin section of dimension $0.9999N$ and pick $N$ so large that $\sqrt{N}$ kills it (as needed).

Comment: great, I still have to put my hands on the book (which might need a few days).

Comment: @Antoine It seems that Pisier does not mention general proportion in his book; see for more general results e.g. Section 1.10.3 in  Brazitikos, Silouanos; Giannopoulos, Apostolos; Valettas, Petros; Vritsiou, Beatrice-Helen Geometry of isotropic convex bodies. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2014.

Comment: @Milkhail, thanks again, but this reference is not to be found where I am :-(. More importantly, I am confused now with your precision: if you take the $n=c N$ Kashin section and then increase the $N$ (say to $N'$), then the subspace you have for $N'$ will not fit in those sections anymore (the codimension will be way too small)...? that is for $N'$, $V_N$ has now codimension $c' N'$ (with $c' << c$) and cannot fit inside a space of dimension $cN'$ or $(1-c)N'$...

Comment: @Antoine The version of the Kashin's result needed here is: For any $\alpha\in(0,1)$ there exists $C=C(\alpha)$ such that for any $N$ there is an $[\alpha N]$-dimensional subspace $L$ of $\ell_1^N$ satisfying $$\forall x\in L\quad \frac1{\sqrt{N}}||x||_1\le||x||_2\le \frac{C}{\sqrt{N}}||x||_1.$$

Comment: @Milkhail:Thanks. Still I am confused... Basically, applying this result for $\alpha \in (0,1)$, can only be useful for finitely many $V_N$ since $\dim V_N = N- o(N)$ so for all $N>N_0(\alpha)$, $V_N$ is not contained in ANY space of dimension $\alpha N$. Since you can apply this result for only finitely many $V_N$, I do not see how you can take "$N$ large so that $\sqrt{N}$ kills the constant". Did I miss something obvious or could you explain your line of thought?

Comment: @Antoine I assume that you want to show that for each $\varepsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ you can find an arbitrarily large $N$  and a subspace $V_N\subset\ell_1^N$ such that dim$(V_N)\ge (1-\varepsilon)N$ and $\sup\{||x||_\infty: x\in V_N, ||x||_1\le 1\}<\delta$. I believe that you can do this using my second and my last comments, as well as the fact that for vectors with nontrivial $||\cdot||_\infty$-norm, $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ norms are close to each other.

Comment: Well, that does not the question I had then... nonetheless very interesting! Many thanks!

Comment: OK, it shows that the answer to the question in your first paragraph is "No". It seems that you meant something else.

Comment: well, I am utterly confused then. Because in my first paragraph, as soon as you go to larger $N$ the codimension decreases (in proportion). So putting the $\forall \epsilon$ at the beginning is not a correct reformultion. A 'No' would be [here I am putting $n = \tfrac{N}{\ln N}$] "for all $\delta$ and for arbitrarily large $N$, there is a supspace such that $\dim(V_N) \geq N - \frac{N}{\ln N}$ and  $\sup \lbrace \|x\|_\infty : x \in V_N, \|x\|_1 \leq 1 \rbrace < \delta$. This is why I thought (in my first comment) that the answer had to rely on how the "constant" $C$ depends on $\alpha$.

Comment: @Antoine See my improved answer.

Comment: many thanks for writing the details| After a night's sleep, my confusion was gone .

Answer (score 6):

I discussed this question with Pisier over lunch.  He later called my attention to the paper

[GG] Garnaev, A. Yu.; Gluskin, E. D.;
The widths of a Euclidean ball. (Russian)
Dokl. Akad. Nauk 277 (1984), 1048–1052.

Pisier emailed me,

“They get an equivalent of the relevant  Kolmogorov numbers
of inclusion of $n$-dim Euclidean space into $\ell_\infty^n$.

It says (from my book on the volume p. 81 but there is a misprint- I checked it must be $+1/2$ in the exponent of the log not $-1/2$):
$ L_1^N$ contains a subspace of codimension $N-n$
with Banach-Mazur distance to Hilbert at most

$$
\min \{ \sqrt{N},  (N/n)^{1/2} [\log (1+  N/n)] ^{1/2}\ ”
$$

Thus the OP’s question has a negative answer if $n^{-1}\log (1+  N/n)$ tends to zero; i.e., if  $n^{-1}\log N \to 0$. What if $n\to \infty$ slower than $\log N$?

Take an $n$ codimensional subspace $V_N$ of $\ell_1^N$.  Take an Auerbach basis $y_1,\dots, y_n$ for $V_N^\perp \subset \ell_\infty^N$.
Let $1/\epsilon $ be a positive integer; something like $\epsilon = 1/10$ is OK. Tile $[-1, 1]^n$ with boxes of side length $\epsilon/n$; the number of boxes is around $(2n\epsilon/n)^n$. Consequently, if $N> (2n\epsilon)^n$, there exist $1\le i < j \le N$ s.t. $(\langle y_k, e_i \rangle)_{k=1}^n$ and $(\langle y_k, e_j \rangle)_{k=1}^n$ lie in the same box.  Since $y_1,\dots, y_n$ is Auerbach, this means that 
$|\langle y, e_i -e_j\rangle| < \epsilon $ for all norm one $y \in V_N^\perp$.  That is, the distance of $e_i -e_j$ to $V_N$ is less than $\epsilon$. Since $\|e_i -e_j\|_1 = 2$ and $\|e_i -e_j\|_\infty =1$, this gives a positive answer to the OP’s question if $N > (2n\epsilon)^n$ for infinitely many $N$; i.e., if $n\log n < \delta \log N$ for a computable $\delta$.

I don’t know where the break point occurs.

Answer (score 3):

By Kashin's theorem you can decompose $\ell_1^{2n}$ into two orthogonal subspaces each of dimension $n$ so that you have $\|x\|_1$ is about $\sqrt{n}\|x\|_2$ for all $x$ in each of these subspaces. So by a trivial estimate between $\|x\|_2$ and $\|x\|_{\infty}$ norms you get $\|x\|_{\infty}$ less than in the order of $1/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: I meant n is small o of N, i.e. $n/N \to 0$. But your two subspaces have half the dimension.